# AngularJS' ng-click treats integer as a string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've got a simple upVote/downVote counter. It works great on the downvote, but when you click upvote it appends a 1 onto the end of the original upvote variable. (it Doesn't **add**, it **Appends**) but only for the upvote. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
<span>
<a ng-click="upCount = upCount + 1" ng-init="upCount=location.upVoteCount" 
class="btn btn-success">{{upCount}}
</a>

<a ng-click="downCount = downCount - 1" ng-init="downCount=location.downVoteCount" 
class="btn btn-danger">{{downCount}}
</a>
</span>
```

Note: both location.upVoteCount and location.downVoteCount are defined as integers. They are populated using ng-repeat="location in locationList". So their values are not explicitly declared in the controller. Changing the + to a - works just fine, the add function also works if you replace location.upVoteCount (or location.downVoteCount) with a number.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're having a problem unless the location entity has strings on it. I just did a quick fiddle and it works fine. Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <span>
<a ng-click="upCount = upCount + 1" href="#" ng-init="upCount=location.upVoteCount">Up: {{upCount}}</a>
<a ng-click="downCount = downCount - 1" href="#" ng-init="downCount=location.downVoteCount">Down: {{downCount}}</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.location = {
        upVoteCount: 0,
        downVoteCount: 0
    };
});
```

It works just fine up or down voting. Run it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/bPQXJ/

Comment: That's strange. my location.upVoteCount and location.downVoteCount are both being pulled in using ng-repeat="location in locationList". So their values are not explicitly declare in the controller. Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: Should be fine as long as the values on location in locationList are not strings. How is locationList being populated?

Comment: Ok I figure it out. I left some bit of old test code in the controller that used the upVoteCount variable. Once I deleted that everything worked just as it should. Thank you!

Comment: @JeremyLikness , just quick question. I saw your jsfiddle and it works fine. Just curios, if value for object `upVoteCount: "0"` `String`, can we convert the `String` value to `int` inside ng-click ? thanks!

Comment: There is no `int` in JavaScript, but you can case to `Number`

Answer (score 3):

`+` means both "add" and "concatenate" while `-` means "minus".

Force the variables to operate in addition mode:

```
upCount = (parseInt(upCount) + 1)
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track here, but that resets the {{upCount}} value to 1 and then you can no longer continue to upvote. It stays at 1

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a ng-click="upCount = upCount + 1" ng-init="upCount=parseInt(location.upVoteCount)" 
class="btn btn-success">{{upCount}}
</a>

<a ng-click="downCount = downCount - 1" ng-init="downCount=parseInt(location.downVoteCount)" 
class="btn btn-danger">{{downCount}}
</a>
```

### Update

If your location.upVoteCount and location.downVoteCount variables aren't integers/numbers then this might be an issue.

Try parsing then first. See ng-init `directive` above.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution freezes the button, in other words, nothing happens when you upvote it or down vote it.

Comment: of what type is `$scope.upCount` and `$scope.downCount` in your controller?

Comment: Neither upCount or downCount are used in the controller. they are just variables similar to what's used in the Angular example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick

Comment: Then this will have to be an issue with your `location.upVoteCount` and `location.downVoteCount`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in a position to try it out right now, but how about:

```
ng-click="upCount = upCount - (-1)"
```

No + operators to confuse the expression evaluator